# How do I access Custom Metrics and Custom Dimensions from Google Core Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics

I have defined a few Custom Metrics and Custom Dimensions. I can see and use them in my custom reports or as secondary dimensions in my standard reports.

I am unable to access them from the Core Reporting API. I expected to be able to extract them in a manner that is similar to Custom Variables.

I have so far been unable to do this or to find any documentation on this besides this reference

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/features/customdimsmets#reporting

```
After the collection, configuration, and other processing stages of 
the pipeline are complete, custom dimensions and metrics become available
via the web reporting interface or th Core Reporting API.
```

To me this reads like it should be possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As of 01 May 2013, according to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/customvars

Custom Var cannot be used with any metrics, which makes them useless...I'll be delighted if someone tells me I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out : https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/analytics/v3/java/latest/

Check the method: Analytics.Data.Ga.get(String ids,
                        String startDate,
                        String endDate,
                        ***String metrics***)
Parameters:

.....

**metrics** - A comma-separated list of Analytics metrics. E.g., 'ga:visits,ga:pageviews'. At least one metric must be specified.

I think the 4th parameter is a way to retrieve filtered reports based on custom variables, dimensions, or metrics.